# AWS Glue python Shell library import error (pyodbc)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyodbc, aws-glue, egg

I am trying to import pyodbc library in Glue python shell. There is some import error.

### ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: the error told you everything. Did you install the required libraries?

Comment: @adrtam yes I have added the libodbc.so.2 file in the same directory, but it does not read it. 
This is the structure of egg file.
- pyodbc.egg
  -- libodbc.so.2
  -- pyodbc.so

Comment: No. Same directory doesn't work, unless you set your LD_PRELOAD environment variable or some others to pick up the local directory. Correct way to install is to put it in /usr/lib

Comment: @adrtam I have tried placing the logodbc.so.2 file in /usr/lib path. Still no luck.

Comment: what distribution/OS? how you get your libodbc.so? why not install that by rpm (redhat/centos) or dpkg (debian/ubuntu) or pkg (freebsd)?

Comment: @adrtam, I am trying to use pyodbc library in glue python shell. To create the package I am using amazon linux image. In that I am installing all dependencies including (unixODBC, unixODBC-dev, pyodbc). After this I am downloading the code of pyodbc and creating the egg file using setup.py file.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925535/9214517